# Lexus CT200h "stuck" in neutral after accident

Tags: electrical, battery, starting, automatic-transmission, troubleshooting

I bought 2018 Lexus CT200h with slightly damaged front and it won't shift into Drive or Parking. After I push Start button it shows me that the car is in Neutral. Trying to put it into Drive or pressing Parking button makes no difference, it just stays in Neutral.

Is this something my car "did" because of the accident?

Comment: It's possible, but really can't tell until you figure why it won't shift. Even then it may not be proven. It could be as simple as a loose or broken connector.

Comment: Any tranmission codes showing up?

Comment: While I suppose it's possible that this issue is unrelated to the accident damage, I strongly suspect that the accident caused this.

Comment: Are you saying it worked when you bought it, or you bought it not working?

Answer (score 0):

I just  a hunch but check to see if there is anything stuck in the linkage under the hood  that goes to the  transmission shifter leaver I once had a little stone in there and once removed it was fine.

Comment: Hey Ron, Thanks for joining the Mechanics Stack Exchange and for posting your first answer.
I believe this answer would be more suited for a Comment as it does not provide a definitive answer to the question.
It is however a very useful troubleshooting step.
However I believe this may be something we cannot realistically provide a sure-fire answer for do the the nature of the issue.